# Logging in to phpBB forum programmatically through C#

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, phpbb

I'm working on a C# application that needs to scrape some data from a phpBB forum. The forum scraping requires logging in. The application will prompt the user for their login credentials to connect.

I've scraped websites before with C#, but what I'm not sure how to do is login to phpBB and keep a session open during the duration of the screen scraping. I've done some searching and haven't had much luck. Is there a good way to programmatically do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what you've tried, but if you used an HttpWebRequest object to retrieve pages and/or logon, then you need to assign a new CookieContainer collection to the HttpWebRequest to store any cookies returned by the website. Share this amongst HttpWebRequest objects to remain logged in

Answer (score 0):

look for the names of the username and password fields using Firebug or Chrome (or even View Source), then use my answer here: [Programmatically logging into a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275858/programmatically-logging-into-a-site/6275876#6275876), replacing 'session_key' and 'session_password' as appropriate. that *should* work.

and then translate to C#!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

Comment: I plan to use HTML Agility Pack to scrape and parse the content, but how will it help logging in to the forum?

Comment: You can use a NetworkCredential to specify a username/password when loading a document.  See http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/207254

Comment: NetworkCredential will do you no good--the login system is all via POST and HTML, not HTTP 401.

Comment: @Jeff: this is kind of what I figured, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using WatiN API for doing screen scraping. I have done screen scraping using this API and it does good work.
[Check it out !](http://watin.org/)

Comment: WatiN is a testing framework that opens a browser and executes commands. Automating browser functionality is not what I'm looking for.